# Multiple Apps for Community User

Tags: community

For Salesforce Users, we can create multiple 'Apps' and add relevant Tabs to the Apps.

Is it possible to create such multiple Apps for a Single Community and let Users navigate different apps using 'App Launcher' in Community?

Comment: I think you can do it: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_enable_app_launcher.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

You can create try with creating custom app launcher using lightning component.

Step1. Get Application menu items using below SOQL.

```
Select Id,Type,ApplicationId,Name,Label,Description,IconUrl,StartUrl,InfoUrl,
IsAccessible,IsVisible,LogoUrl,SortOrder,MobileDeviceType from AppMenuItem 
where IsAccessible=true AND Type='TabSet' order by Name ASC
```

Step2. Create Lightning component to show app menus.

**appItems component**

```
<aura:attribute type="AppMenuItem[]" name="apps"/>
<aura:handler  name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}"/>
<lightning:carousel disableAutoRefresh="false" disableAutoScroll="false" class="slds-carousel__pane">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.apps}" var="obj">
                <lightning:carouselImage class="slds-carousel__image"
                                         src = "{!obj.LogoUrl}"
                                         header = "{!obj.Label}"
                                         description = "{!obj.Description}"
                                         alternativeText = "{!obj.Name}"
                                         href = "https://www.salesforce.com">
                </lightning:carouselImage>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:carousel>
```

**appItems.js controller**

```
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {                                                                                        
        var action=  component.get('c.getAllApps');   
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            console.log(response.getState());
            if("SUCCESS"===response.getState())
            {
                console.log('response'+response.getReturnValue());
                component.set('v.apps',response.getReturnValue());     
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
```